# Template argument for function type in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

Here, `Wrapper::set` should be able to take any function or function object that matches the `int(int)` signature, and store it into the `std::function`. It should work with function pointers, lambdas, objects with `operator()`, `std::bind` expressions, etc.

```
#include <functional>

struct Wrapper {
    using function_type = int(int);

    std::function<function_type> func_;

    template<typename Func> void set(Func func) { func_ = func; }
};
```

What would be the best form of `set` so that it works in all cases? I.e. one of

- `set(Func func) { func_ = func; }`
- `set(Func&& func) { func_ = std::forward<Func>(func); }`
- `set(Func& func) { func_ = func; }`
- `set(const Func& func) { func_ = func; }`

Comment: If it was me, I'd have both the `Func&&` and `const Func&` overloads.

Comment: @DeiDei: Because of type-inference, `Func&&` can handle the `const Func&` case as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest version:

```
void set(std::function<function_type> f) {
    func_ = std::move(f);
}
```

The complex version:

```
template <class F,
    class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_assignable<std::function<function_type>&, F&&>::value>
    >
void set(F&& f) {
    func_ = std::forward<F>(f);
}
```

There's no reason to do anything else. Both of these handle every case gracefully and correctly, the simple case has an extra move, which for `std::function` isn't an expensive operation, so I would strongly prefer the simple version unless you have a compelling, proven performance requirement to need the complex one.

Comment: True answer in general, but notice that SFINAE only really makes sense if there are other overloads to choose instead of the disabled one. If all you're after is a compilation error with incompatible types, a `static_assert` is easier to both write and read, and can produce a nicer error message.

Comment: @Angew Not necessarily - it's also useful if something else is inspecting if your function is callable and will do some kind of fallback. Or if you're wrapping this function template in a generic lambda that you're passing to something else, etc.

Comment: The first version wouldn't work on function objects, or on lambdas, when `function_type = int(int).`
Also for the second version, I'm not sure if it can be used with locally defined lambdas, since it doesn't make a copy.

Comment: For SFINAE, i would not use the form `class = std::enable_if_t<cond>` as this form disallows the disable counter part. I prefer `std::enable_if_t<cond>* = nullptr`.

Comment: @tmlen Confused what your typedef meant. Should be taking `std::function<function_type>`, fixed.

Comment: @tmlen What do you mean about locally defined lambdas?

Comment: @Jarod42 There is no disable counterpart here.

Comment: The lambda is defined inside a function, and passed to the `Wrapper`. The lambda then goes out of scope, but the `Wrapper` still has the reference to it. I don't know if `std::function` keeps a copy of the lambda object.

Comment: @tmlen Of course it does. That's basically the purpose of `std::function`.

Comment: @tmlen `std::function` owns its function, yes.

Comment: Why the SFINAE boiler-plate when `set` isn't overloaded anyway? It's going to be an error in all cases when you try to call `foo.set` even with the SFINAE in place, right?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Maybe somebody wants to check if `foo.set` is callable with an argument and, if so, call it, else do something else.

Comment: Note that a default template argument is not a context where SFINAE applies, according to the spec text: "Only invalid types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure." Until we have a clear definition of "immediate context" (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1844), the use of SFINAE in default template arguments is insecure. To be in the safe side, the SFINAE should be put in the template parameter type itself or the function template type.